# What do I call a "normal" variable?

Tags: c++

```
int* p;
int& r;
int i;
double* p2;
double& r2;
double d;
```

p and p2 are pointers, r and r2 are references, but what are i and d? (No, I am not looking for the answer "an int and a double")

I am looking for a name to use for "normal" variables, setting them apart from pointers and references. I don't believe that such a name doesn't exist (after all, I can't be the first one who wants to distinguish them from pointers and references. I do have the feeling that it's something really easy and I'm just missing it here.

Who knows what to call "normal" variables?

**Additional info**

I am looking for a name that can refer to anything but references and pointers, so including classes. The whole same story could be held when the following was included as well:

```
MyClass* p3;
MyClass& r3;
MyClass c;
```

I am *not* looking for a way to refer to `i`, a way to refer to `d` and a way to `c`. I am looking for a way to refer to the group (of non-references, non-pointers) which `i`, `d` and `c` are part of.

Comment: Is this a question about language semantics or about naming conventions for variables?

Comment: Just looking for what's in common between `int` and `double`, but not the other types I come up with "variables of arithmetic type" or possibly variable of non-pointer object type? It would help if you define exactly what set of entities you mean. Are variables of class type included?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Anything but pointers and references - I just used int and double as examples

Comment: What is wrong with calling them just variables? In fact, all of those are variables, their data type differs though, but they're all variables (unless you declare them in a type, then they're fields.)

Comment: References surely aren't variables in current C++.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: What's wrong with that? Well... the fact that I want to be able to distinguish between these, pointers and references

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Value types** (value variables) was my first thought, but it seems to make some people uncomfortable, so **nonreferential types** (nonreferential variables) works just as well: pointers and references are both "referential types" in the sense that they refer to another location, while ordinary value types do not.

Answer (score 7):

Pointers and references are variables as well. I think it is sufficient to say that `i is a variable of type int` and `p is a variable of type pointer to int`. If they are members of a class `i is a member variable of type int` would be the most precise description.

Edit: There is no definite answer to your question. `int` would be a `fundamental type` in standard terminology. Other types as classes, unions **and** pointers are called `compound types`. This just isn't helpful in your case as you would refer to

```
A* a;
int* b;
A c;
```

as only consisting of compound types. But you want to emphasize that you use pointers. Just say it.

Comment: But hey, I didn't ask for what's sufficient to say, or what's the most precise description. I asked for a name for the group of non-reference non-pointer variables. A name which allows me to say, I am using pointers all over the place, but there in many cases there is no reason to do so, so I should change them to <normal variable>s wherever possible.

Comment: @Jasper: In C++, the name is "fundamental types".

Comment: @Jasper: You could say: "I am using pointers all over the place, but there are many cases where there is no reason to do so, so I should remove the levels of indirection in these places."

Answer (score 7):

If I understand what you are talking about, I would call it a value type.

Comment: I just grabbed my copy of "Elements of Programming" and thought about it: a sequence of bits together with a pointer type would constitute a value type as well. Do you refer to another definition of value type?

Comment: @pmr - Whlie you could certainly treat a pointer as a value, eventually we really care about the value that the pointer references.  I don't have a copy of the book in front of me, but I would expect that in context the interpretation of the bits as something other than a reference to something is implied.

Comment: @tv I realized that the term `value type` is used in C# to mean exactly what the OP is looking for. Unfortunately there is no such term in C++.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the official terminology, then the C++ standard defines:

- *fundamental types*, built-in value types such as `int` and `double`, and
- *compound types*, including pointers and references, and also arrays, functions, classes, unions and enumerations.

It also uses the terms "object types", "reference types" and "function types", but it seems a bit vague to me about whether a pointer is an "object type" or a "reference type".

If you want to include fundamental types and classes, I would use the term "object type", and leave it to pedants to quibble about whether that should include pointers.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but I was looking for a name for the group in which classes are also included. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear from my question.

Answer (score 1):

They are just variables. Not *pointers* and not *references*, **variables**.

Comment: So you would talk about member references instead of reference member variables?

Comment: In the specific case of members, the standard calls them *member* in general (that includes function members) and *data member* to discriminate from typedefs, subclasses, function members... In general you will see that people call them *member variables* or *attributes*, sometimes plain *variables*. Note that this applies to all data, regardless of whether it is an instance, a pointer or a reference. When talking, make the language as clear as possible. *A member of pointer to T type* is much clearer than a *pointer member* (note that *pointer **to** member* is a whole different thing)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use "non-pointer and non-reference type". There is no name especially designed for your purpose, i think.

> A name which allows me to say, I am using pointers all over the place, but there in many cases there is no reason to do so, so I should change them to s wherever possible.

It sounds to me you look rather for "pass by copy" or "copy" vs "pass by reference" or "reference". The fact that you can pass a pointer by value makes it impossible to use an absolute term, but makes it necessary to use a term tied to the usecase:

```
int **p;
```

Is this a variable used to change a pointer of type `int*` (then it would be "pass by reference" in the sense you aim to modify the referent. To clarify that a pointer is used, you may wish to use the term "pass by pointer" too), or is this variable just used to hold a value of type `int**` (then it would be "pass by value" in the sense that you copy such a value)?

Comment: I'm not looking for "pass by" terminology, I am looking for (member) variable terminology.

Comment: @Jasper then use "copy" or "reference", i think. As in "i hold that variable by reference in my class"

Answer (score 0):

Values, or variables.

Comment: A pointer (which is simply another type) has a value as well. In general, values are the concrete instances of types.

Comment: I was just thinking pass by value, as opposed to pass by reference or pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `d` are consistently called *objects* in the C++ standard. But, then again, so are `p`, `p2`, and objects of class type such as the "c" of `MyClass c;`.

Personally I like calling `i`, `d`, and `p` objects, though it might be a little bit confusing to programmers of other languages such as Java, where they would be known as *primitive variables* with the term *objects* reserved for instances of classes.

**EDIT:** Instead of

> I am using pointers all over the place, but there are many cases where there is no reason to do so, so I should change them to <normal variable>s wherever possible.

I would say: "I am using pointers all over the place, but there are many cases where there is no reason to do so, so I should remove the levels of indirection wherever possible."

Comment: I gave an example as I thought there to be an answer usable in many more cases than just the one I am facing and I didn't want to complicate the matter. However, the real case I am facing is a bit more complicated: I have removed the usage of pointers in a large project and I want to give a description of where, when and how I turned them into references/"objects"

Answer (score 0):

I typically call those "plain ol' data" (POD) variables, after the convention of referring to a `struct` as "POD" if it contains only data members (no functions).  That's not an official convention, but it gets the point across (for simple types like `int` and `float`, it doesn't apply for classes).

I have also heard these types of variables called "concrete" variables.  I think the distinction that was trying to be made is that these variables *are* something in and of themselves, whereas pointers and references simply tell you about some other piece of data somewhere else.

More than anything else, I hear these "loose" variables (that is, not a member of another object) referred to simply by their type (integer, floating-point number, class, etc).

Comment: POD is something else, it's a narrower concept, as there are things you can do with PODs that you cannot with complex classes (actually, POD is defined in the standard - the next standard is actually going to change that definition slightly)

Answer (score -1):

I think we should call them OBJECTs. I think it's no need to be that strict.

Consider:

```
typedef int *, pint;
pint foo;
```

What do you think **foo** is?